# multiple queries to delete rows from table

Tags: php, mysql

How would I run a code where it checks `table1` for the column `postid` and then searches `table2` to see if that value actually exists. If it does exist then move onto the next but if it doesn't it removes the row from `table1`.

So if in `table1` I have a row which has 3 rows: a `postid` of `333` another of `444` and another of `555`.

Let's say `333` doesn't exist in `table2` then I need to delete the row which contains that `postid`  from `table1` and move onto the next. It keeps doing that until all the rows are checked.

How would I accomplish this? I am very confused and haven’t been able to think of everything.

Comment: I thought people could read :)  I am very confused and haven’t been able to think of everything.

Comment: Or maybe people can point someone in the right direction if they don't know how to do something. Very helpful :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're iterating the post ids, you can perform this type of delete for each postid:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE postid = 333 AND 333 NOT IN (SELECT postid FROM table2 WHERE postid = 333);
```

Or, delete all rows from table1 that does not have a record with a matching postid in table2 (assuming table2.postid column is defined as NOT NULL):

```
DELETE table1 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table2.postid = table1.postid) WHERE table2.postid IS NULL;
```

Comment: Well if I was doing this manually I would, first SELECT * FROM table1. Then chose the first row and copy it's postid value - let's make it 2. Then I would: SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE postid='2'. Then if it showed no results I would: DELETE FROM table1 WHERE postid='2' but if it showed a result I would do the same thing but with the next postid. I want to do this automatically so that i'm not making multiple queries and spending hours on it.

Comment: Super! That worked great! I kind of understand it now as well. Thanks for helping unlike some :)